# jquery masonry not working on odd window resolution

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, resolution, jquery-masonry

You can see it here http://obecadmin.dev.f13.cz/ on resolutions from 1000 to about 1400, almost every odd(1379 etc) width resolution causes boxes to be positioned under each other instead of two columns.. any idea what could be wrong?

The whole site is responsive so each for is 50% and masonry is inited with

```
columnWidth: function(containerWidth) {
    return (containerWidth / 2);
},
```

I tried to Math.floor the containerWidth/2, cause I thought it was calculating the width wrong(+1px that is should have), but it only cause the wrong positioning happen on even resolutions..

Github issue here https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/274

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your problem is with odd numbers. try this

```
columnWidth: function(containerWidth) {
    var size = (containerWidth / 2);

    if(!isEven(size))
        size = size + 1;
    return size;
}

function isEven(value) {
    return (value%2 == 0);
}
```

Comment: well that didn't really work, it pretty much made not only odd, but even numbers not work either, at least in range from 1200 to 1300, this is all actually pretty random, so I wouldn't focus on the odd numbers only, the problem must be either in my css, as it's using a fluid responsive grid, or the masonry itself

Comment: @foxx In my test it worked just fine. I cant duplicate the same problem on even numbers using Chrome.

Comment: The problem is *not* really with the odd numbers.. besides, what you are suggesting *can't* even work.. let's say the wrapping element have 998px width, 50% is 499px, which is an odd number, I'd add 1px to each box, which would result in them having 1000px in total, which is more than my wrapping element, which would only result in boxes being sorted under each other.

Comment: @foxx then you can add a check to see if thats the case and subtract 1

Comment: That wouldn't work either, https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/274 creator of the plugin made me try and put the width to 49% instead of 50, to give it a little more space for miscalculations, yet it didn't work, not even on 40%(again just on some resolutions)..